# A small question about background and calc()

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, calc, background-position

all.

I'm working on a project. I have small question. about calc function.

as everyone know..
it's working on all browsers..

========== ok =============

```
background-color:#dfdfdf;
background-image:url(..);
background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

but why next code doesn't working on IE11??

==========do not working on IE 11 =============

```
background:#dfdfdf url(..) no-repeat calc(100% - 10px) center;
```

-_-;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: so.. it's IE's rules right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ie11 must be used separately

```css
body
     {
background:#dfdfdf url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg") no-repeat;
background-position:calc(100% - 100px) center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
     <title>Page Title</title>
     <meta name="description" content="Write some words to describe your html page">
   
</head>
<body>


</body>

</html>
```